# Realtek audio AC 97 5.1 on Windows 7: Terrible subwoofer quality

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I have a media center PC with on-board Realtek AC97 Audio. I have been using Windows XP for a couple of years with great audio quality.

I just upgraded this PC with Windows 7 and installed the latest Realtek drivers from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/

At the testing screen, all the speakers works correctly (including subwoofer). Despite that, while playing any movie or music, the subwoofer quality is terrible. From it it just comes noises, in the correct rhythm but quite low and quite out of tone.

I compensated the loudness by putting the other speakers lower but the sound of the subwoofer is really terrible.

Is there anyone facing the same problem? Does anyone have a workaround for that?

PS.: I had gone past the steps given in [Terrible noises from subwoofer of ACER Aspire 6930 with Realtek sound chip](https://superuser.com/questions/227467/terrible-noises-from-subwoofer-of-acer-aspire-6930-with-realtek-sound-chip) but still I have a bad quality of sound.
My problem is very similar to the one in http://www.mp3car.com/car-audio/143796-realtek-hd-audio-is-robbing-my-subwoofer.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the generic drivers, try using the drivers the vendor provides.  If you have an ASUS mobo, get ASUS's drivers.  If you're running an HP laptop, get HP's drivers.  Most hardware OEMs provide their customers with an SDK for their chips.  The end result is that while many of the OEM drivers work, they can have minor incompatibilities with hardware sold by a given vendor.

I would also try removing the drivers and using the drivers which Windows Update detects for your system.  Microsoft has done a surprisingly good job with their WHQL drivers for Windows 7.

Comment: I have an Intel board and the chipset driver is installed. I also did the online Intel drivers check. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What's the model number of your board?  I've got a DP55WG and there are audio drivers available for my board.  Those are the ones I would try if the OEMs are causing problems.

Comment: My board is Intel 945G. As far as I could tell, the drivers were not provided by Intel but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: Oh, the chipset is Intel.  No, that's not what I mean.  The onboard sound is not typically a part of the chipset driver.  What is the make and model of the PC or system board?

Comment: Could you be more specific when you mean poor subwoofer quality? Do you mean you are not getting the "punch" you expecting? Or are you getting like fuzzy or garbled sound?

Comment: Based on what I read above (again) it sounds like you are not getting enough power from the sound card to drive the subwoofer. I have this problem with my ALC850 and my ATH-m50Rs the sound sounds muddy and quiet. You might need to invest an a small inline amp to boost the signal. Is the subwoofer powered?

Comment: It would be amazing if a PC soundcard was directly driving a subwoofer...

Comment: Never had this issue.  My setup has always been PC > Home Theater receiver > speakers and sub.